# How to apply style in iframe's external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, cross-domain

I'm having a difficulty on applying a css style for this one.
I already tried using this code that I read from similar post regarding the style inside iframe.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#iframePPT').ready(function(){
            $('#iframePPT').contents().find('body').css('display','none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to apply a display:none to some part of the iframe.

```
<iframe id="iframePPT" width="560" height="459" src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.knowledgelink.training%2Fslideshowstorage%2F34_Compliance+%26+Other+Training_ba5726636d2f4412b264e3c47a2833de.pps" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But that script won't work. Are there any ways to apply a style in an iframe with an external link?

Here's a sample screenshot
[image]

I have to remove the toolbar with the redbox.
Are there any ways to remove this?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Long story short. Due to security you are not allowed.

Comment: I see. Thank you for that.

Comment: try it with button click and then fire a click when dom loaded

Comment: Is the iframe on the same origin, or do you have access to the iframe's domain? If not, then it's impossible.

Comment: I don't have access to the iframe's src which is the officeapps.